# Inserting non matching tuples

Tags: mysql, sql, tuples, where-in

I have a table with the following columns: `id`, `store`, `category_id` and `option_id`. The contents of this table are updated via web-hook from an original on a different server. Once the contents are received I will need to check to see what rows need to be deleted and which need to be inserted.

For simplicity let's assume the category and option id tuples I received from the web-hook are (1,1) and (1,2), and that the database already contains (1,1) and (1,3). So (1,3) will need to be deleted and (1,2) will need to be inserted.

I can do deletion fine like this:

```sql
DELETE FROM store_category_options 
 WHERE store=1 AND (category_id, option_id) NOT IN ((1,1), (1,2));
```

Inserting, however, requires two queries, one to retrieve the values already in the database

```sql
SELECT category_id, option_id FROM store_category_options WHERE store=1
```

and then after the difference has been calculated outside of MYSQL another to insert them back:

```sql
INSERT INTO store_category_option (category_id, option_id) VALUES (1,2)
```

I was wondering if there was a way to do the inserts with one query instead of two.

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would all help.

Comment: Why not just delete everything (`TRUNCATE store_category_options`) and then just insert the data from the webhook?

Comment: One has the sense that you're making this far more complicated than it needs to be

Comment: @Strawberry It doesn't matter, this is precisely the question I want to know the answer to, if for no other reason than out of curiosity.

Comment: @Nick there are two reasons I don't delete the whole thing and re insert: firstly it would be inefficient in my case since I don't expect the data to change often and I don't expect the data to change much: The webhook will get called every hour, but I expect only a few rows to change every few months. Secondly there is a timestamp column I would like to preserve that I've not included in the question because I didn't think it was relevant

Comment: In that case you might be best served by making a unique key on `(category_id, option_id)` and using `INSERT IGNORE` which will discard any input data which matches an existing key combination although there are other side-effects, see the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself in the end. We can start with turning the webhook data into a derived table to select from with `WHERE NOT IN`

```sql
SELECT 1 as store_category_id, 1 as store_option_id UNION SELECT 1, 2;
```

In the Mysql CLI this produces the output:

```
+-------------------+-----------------+
| store_category_id | store_option_id |
+-------------------+-----------------+
|                 1 |               1 |
|                 1 |               2 |
+-------------------+-----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

To query this table with a where clause it is necessary to include it in a subquery of another select and give the table an alias:

```sql
SELECT store_category_id, store_option_id FROM (
  SELECT 1 as store_category_id, 1 as store_option_id 
  UNION SELECT 1, 2
) AS vt WHERE store_option_id = 1;
```

This produces the output:

```
+-------------------+-----------------+
| store_category_id | store_option_id |
+-------------------+-----------------+
|                 1 |               1 |
+-------------------+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now we can use a wherein clause combined with another sub query to select the rows to be inserted:

```sql
SELECT store_category_id, store_option_id FROM (
  SELECT 1 as store_category_id, 1 as store_option_id 
  UNION SELECT 1, 2
) AS vt WHERE (category_id, option_id) NOT IN (
  SELECT store_category_id, store_option_id 
  FROM store_category_options
);
```

The result is:

```
+-------------------+-----------------+
| store_category_id | store_option_id |
+-------------------+-----------------+
|                 1 |               2 |
+-------------------+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Finally to insert the rows we have calculated we include the previous select statement inside a INSERT INTO SELECT statement

```sql
INSERT INTO store_category_options 
(store_category_id, store_option_id)
SELECT store_category_id, store_option_id FROM (
    SELECT 1 as store_category_id, 1 as store_option_id 
    UNION SELECT 1, 2
) AS vt WHERE (store_category_id, store_option_id) NOT IN (
    SELECT store_category_id, store_option_id 
    FROM store_category_options
);
```